# mongoose @prop() decorator type:Object in schema definition _ NestJS

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I recently moved to NestJs . I have some doubts for defining properties for mongoose schema .

how can I define object type inside schema :

in express I defined such properties like this:

```
 foo:{
        type: Object
    },
```

now here I cannot use Object type. I did use **any** keyword too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find my answer, we can define type to any and inside @prop() decorator use:
{ type: Object }

```
  @Prop({ type: Object })
  foo: any;
```